# Check if class name (a string) is used for some class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, namespaces, metaprogramming

How do I get the exact class variable which is (in current scope) available under a given name? I want to write a function like this:

```py
from my_module import ClassA # A subclass of my_other_module.BenevolentClass
from my_other_module import my_function
a = 'ClassA'
cls_var = my_function(a)
o = cls_var()
```

So that I could supply any string to my_function and so long as that string is available in the caller's namespace as a class name, it would produce the correct class much like if I copypasted the string directly to the code. The reason is that I need to supply class names to a complex object creation routine, but avoid `eval` when possible. My current implementation is like this:

```py
def my_function(name):
    if name in globals():
        c = globals()[name]
        # Actually a complex class whitelist
        if issubclass(c, BenevolentClass):
            return c
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'Potentially malicious class {name}')
```

But that apparently produces globals() from my_other_module, which is not what I want. I want all classes that are available at the exact line of code where `my_function` is called (which may be inside completely different module which is called from yet another one).

Comment: Do you want to return the class from the Global scope or is it an attribute of the class?

Comment: It is neither, otherwise `globals()` or `getattr` would work. It's some other class, defined in arbitrary place, but available in the calling namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a solution. Not sure it is perfect, so I'd rather hear some comments before accepting my own answer.

```py
import inspect

def my_function(name):
    for frame in inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe()):
        c = None
        if name in frame.frame.f_globals:
            c = frame.frame.f_globals[name]
            break
    if c and issubclass(c, BenevolentClass):
        return c
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'Potentially malicious class {name}')
```

As far as I understand it, `inspect.getouterframes` walks outwards along the call stack, and I can check globals on every step to see what's available. Neither local variables nor builtins are available in `frame.f_globals`, so it doesn't seem to have much potential for injecting malicious data.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the global dict to my_function.

```
def my_function(name, g):
    if name in g:
        ...

cls_var = my_function(a, globals())
```